# javascript library in my Java project?

Tags: javascript, java

I am working on a project in Java that involves designing a speedometer. I am looking for any libraries that I can possibly use. However, I found a lot of such "gauge libraries"  for javascript. Is there any way I can implement this javascript library in my project Java?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its all depend on the architecture of your application, for example building a reactive application on the JVM, using a technology like [Vert.x](http://vertx.io/) will allow you to do that.

I strongly recommend vert.x, you will find a lot of magic there

Comment: Thank you so much Adel Bachene for the quick response. It was indeed very useful :)